# "ImportError: No module named scipy" after installing the scipy package

Tags: python, pip, scipy

So I recently tried to install scipy on my Raspbian (Debian for Raspberry Pi) operating system using `sudo pip install scipy`. The command worked without too much trouble, and I can see the file located under `pi/build/scipy`.

However, when I actually try to import it in a python program, it gives me `ImportError: No module named scipy` I'm not really sure how to go about pointing the OS in the correct location to import the scipy module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are inside the pip environment it won't work, at all. I would recommend you to install the `python-scipy` package instead, which would assure you that will work:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install python-scipy
Selecting previously unselected package python-decorator.
(Reading database ... 252269 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-decorator_3.4.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-decorator (3.4.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-scipy.
Preparing to unpack .../python-scipy_0.13.3-2+b1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking python-scipy (0.13.3-2+b1) ...
Setting up python-decorator (3.4.0-2) ...
Setting up python-scipy (0.13.3-2+b1) ...
➜  ~  python
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun  3 2014, 23:36:29) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>>
```

Comment: this method does not work. it fails to get the package from all the mirrors it attempts to get it from.

Comment: @PhilipR. it worked in my system perfectly fine. Exactly what is the error?

Comment: "Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/python-scipy/python-scipy_0.10.1+dfsg2-1_armhf.deb Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'" it repeats this multiple times with slight variations in the URL.

Comment: @PhilipR. you don't have internet in the raspi, the DNS or the mirrors are down. Is a problem local to you.

Comment: oh wow... now i feel dumb, haha. why didnt i check this first? its plugged in to the ethernet cable, but its not actually giving me access for whatever reason.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have a problem with the permissions after installing with `sudo pip`. (

A quick solution to this problem could be to install scipy with

```
sudo -i
pip install scipy
```

To get the `sudo`-install working you might need to change your default `umask` (`umask 0022`).

Comment: I used the exaxct same sudo pip command to install matplotlib, which imports just fine at this point.